# Accept SSL certificates in Selenium Opera C#

Tags: selenium, c#

I am trying to launch an Opera web driver, but whenever I go to the homepage of the site under test, I get certificate errors.

I have tried using the `CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates = true:`

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
....
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("xxx"), caps);
```

But I still get an invalid certificate error. Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your path to the opera profile, it need to be no space and correct path.

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera();
 capabilities.setCapability("opera.profile", 
     new OperaProfile(System.getProperty("user.home") + 
         "/APPData/Roaming/Opera/Opera")); 
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
 WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);
```